# Re-Draw QuadMesh collection after Axis clear

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating a pcolormesh plot, as shown below. The ax.pcolormesh call returns a [matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh) object.

Is it possible to save this object in a variable, clear the axis (or figure?), plot something else and then later re-draw the initial pcolormesh using the saved matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh object?

I'm trying to avoid having to call ax.pcolormesh again.

Small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np;

counter = 0;

def onClick(event):
    global counter;
    counter += 1;

    ax.clear();

    if counter % 2:
        # Plot something else
        ax.plot(x1, x2)
    else:
        # Re-draw the initial pcolormesh using quadMeshCol?
        pass;

    fig.canvas.draw();

x1 = np.random.randn(100);
x2 = np.random.randn(100);
x3 = np.random.randn(100, 100);

fig, ax = plt.subplots();

quadMeshCol = ax.pcolormesh(x1, x2, x3);

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onClick);

plt.show();
```

I have been trying to do this all morning, but haven't had any success.
I did see that the matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh object has a draw method, however it requires a renderer and I don't know how to get one of those.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the purpose of this code is to switch back and forth between two plots. So instead of recreating the content in a single axes multiple times you probably just want to use two axes. One for the plot, one for the colormesh. Depending on the counter, you set either one invisible and possibly draw some new content to the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

counter = 0

def onClick(event):
    global counter
    counter += 1

    if counter % 2:
        # Plot something else
        ax2.clear()
        ax2.plot(x1, x2)
        ax.set_visible(False)
        ax2.set_visible(True)

    else:
        ax.set_visible(True)
        ax2.set_visible(False)

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

x1 = np.random.randn(100)
x2 = np.random.randn(100)
x3 = np.random.randn(100, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
ax2= fig.add_subplot(111, label="2")
ax2.set_visible(False)

quadMeshCol = ax.pcolormesh(x1, x2, x3)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onClick)

plt.show()
```

Or even more compact:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onClick(event):
    ax.set_visible(not ax.get_visible())
    ax2.set_visible(not ax2.get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

x1 = np.random.randn(100)
x2 = np.random.randn(100)
x3 = np.random.randn(100, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
ax2= fig.add_subplot(111, label="2")
ax2.set_visible(False)

quadMeshCol = ax.pcolormesh(x1, x2, x3)
line, = ax2.plot(x1, x2)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onClick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was after. Didn't realise that was possible. Thanks.